# How do I drop weapons on PS4?

Tags: ps4, killing-floor-2

There was a dedicated button for dropping weapons on PC, but I'm not sure if there is one on PS4. While playing online, I died, so my friend picked my gun up so he could give it back to me when I respawned. Unfortunately, neither of us could figure out how to drop it and when I checked the control scheme in-game, there was no button for dropping weapons.

Is there a way to drop a weapon on PS4? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to drop your weapon, though as noted in the question, there is *not* a dedicated button for it. After searching for a while, I found [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/124913-killing-floor-2/74632843) that explains how to do it:

> You have to be holding the weapon, hold triangle and hit R1

Thus, to drop a weapon, equip it, hold triangle, and press R1.

[image: image gun menu]

It's worth noting there are some weapons that you *cannot* drop, such as the 9mm and your knife. These do not take up any weight, so it will not affect what you can carry, though.